# Jquery Mobile Collapsible Listview Align Text and Button

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Here is what I'm doing:  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upP3g/)

I want the word 'New' horizontally centered and the buttons "Something" and the Flipswitch vertically centered.

Is it possible?

I tried it but It doesn't work:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="text-align: center !important;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center !important;">New</h2>


            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-right">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-li-count">Something</a>
            </div>


            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-right">
                <select data-role="flipswitch"> 
                    <option value="Off">Off</option>
                    <option value="On" selected="selected">On</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.4 and Jquery 1.10.2, but I'm not so good with css.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LwNX4/)?

Comment: wooow thanks so much. It is better then I imagined ^^.
You are great.
Post an answer, then I accept like the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For buttons and flip switch, wrap each element in a `span` with class `ui-btn-right` to align it to right side.

```
<li data-icon="false">
  <a href="#">Type 1</a>
  <span class="ui-btn-right">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-mini">Something</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

To center align collapsible's header, you need to override `ui-collapsible-heading-toggle`.

#### updated

Based on @ezanker's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641518/jquery-mobile-collapsible-listview-align-text-and-button/22642625#comment34485342_22642625)

```
.ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

li > a.ui-btn {
  padding-right: 120px;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LwNX4/)**

Comment: @Omar, a couple of small additions: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LwNX4/5/ (equalize padding on heading to compensate for the icon on the right, and prevent text from overlapping buttons in the LI)